# Interface constraints for interface instances in Idris

Tags: idris

I am just starting to learn Idris coming from Haskell, and I'm trying to write some simple linear algebra code.

I want to write a `Num` interface instance for `Vect`, but specifically for `Vect n a` with the constraint that `a` has a `Num` instance.

In Haskell I would write a typeclass instance like this:

```hs
instance Num a => Num (Vect n a) where
  (+) a b = (+) <$> a <*> b
  (*) a b = (*) <$> a <*> b
  fromInteger a = a : Nil
```

But reading the Idris [interface docs](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#idiom-brackets) does not seem to mention constraints on interface instances.

The best I can do is the following, which predictably causes the compiler to lament about `a` not being a numeric type:

```
Num (Vect n a) where
  (+) Nil Nil = Nil
  (+) (x :: xs) (y :: ys) = x + y :: xs + ys
  (*) Nil Nil = Nil
  (*) (x :: xs) (y :: ys) = x * y :: xs * ys
  fromInteger i = Vect 1 (fromInteger i)
```

I can work around this by creating my own vector type with a `Num` constraint (which isn't portable) or by overloading `(+)` in a namespace (which feels a little clunky):

```
namespace Vect
  (+) : Num a => Vect n a -> Vect n a -> Vect n a
  (+) xs ys = (+) <$> xs <*> ys
```

Is there a way to constrain interface implementations, or is there a better way to accomplish this, eg using dependent types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Idris, you'd do (almost) the same as haskell

```
Num a => Num (Vect n a) where
```

Like a number of things, this is in [the book](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) but not, apparently, in the docs.

Comment: Much appreciated! I was planning to pick up a copy at some point anyway, but it certainly is worrying that the docs aren't complete. I might update them when I get the chance.